# display array index value JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

Lets say I retrieve data from my local api, using this snippet

```
{console.log("Bin", this.state.rows.filter(qc => qc.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs.length > 0).map((bin) => bin))}
```

I retrieve a result that looks something like this

```
    0: {…}
    1: {…}
    2: {…}
```

As a place holder, this is what I have

```
<div className="column-label qc-number">{this.state.rows.filter(bin => bin.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs.length > 0).length}</div>
```

**If I wanted to display each index value of that map, how would I be able to do that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{console.log("Bin", this.state.rows.filter(qc => qc.BinsByDayByOrchardsQCs.length > 0).map((bin, i) => i))}
```

Second argument in map method is the index. If you want to give them both back I suggest an array `[bin, i]` or object `{bin: bin, index: i}`

Comment: or map((bin, index) => { ...bin, index }) to maintain all properties and add index as a property